# English usage: "Are we done?" and "He is gone"

Tags: idioms, colloquial-language

1. "Are we done ? "
2. He is gone

I used to hear the above sentences from some of English speaking acquaintances. I was wondering whether theses sentences are grammatically correct or poeple are speaking it wrong. Kindly explain me.

Comment: What makes you believe that they might not be correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Done** is American English for "finished", meaning that you have completed your tasks or reached the end of something or that you will spend no more time on something.  It is typically used with the verb "be" in front of it, often in the phrase "I'm done" and sometimes with a complement preceded by *with* (as in "I'm done with your nonsense").

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/done) defines it as follows:

> arrived at or brought to an end

It gives the example "One more question and we're done".  This usage of "done" may be somewhat colloquial but I don't see how you can call it "wrong", still less ungrammatical.

"He is **gone**" is perfectly OK, since past participles can be used as adjectives, and the use of "gone" as an adjective is well established  - so much so that it has an entry for its adjectival uses in some dictionaries ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gone); [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gone)).